# Filtering sdp packets using pcap

Tags: c++, wireshark, network-protocols, pcap, sdp

I want to filter  sdp packets to be able to identify the possible sessions initiations for rtp streams. I'm using pcap library for c++ to read the packets and  I would like to write a parser for sdp packets but I don't know which protocols can encapsulate sdp other than SIP and  MGCP (I mean after UDP). Or If anybody can shed any light on how does wireshark filters/identifys SDP packets.

Comment: im not sure but i think what you are looking for is called 'sdp dissector'. dissectors are the protocol level parsers

Comment: I'm building my own disector using a grammar parsing library. But inorder to write the grammar I need to know which protocols can encapsulate the SDP protocol. For example a possible stack is: Ether | IP | UDP | SIP | SDP or Ether | IP | UDP |  MGCP | SDP. But I need to know what other protocols can be headers for sdp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we limit ourselves to the protocols over which SDP can *directly* run, then, if we look at the current master-branch version of Wireshark:

- any protocol that uses a media type to describe its payload could, in principle, carry SDP, with a media type value of "application/sdp", although I don't know whether, in practice, you'll ever see, for example, SDP-over-HTTP rather than, say, SDP-over-SIP;
- the BICC bearer control tunneling protocol, specified in ITU-T Recommendation [Q.1990](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-Q.1990-200107-I/en), can carry SDP, with the Tunneled Protocol Indicator having the value of 0x20 for SDP;
- the Cisco Session Management protocol can carry SDP;
- the [ISUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISDN_User_Part) (ISDN User Part) protocol can carry SDP;
- the Gateway Control protocol ([RFC 3525](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3525); an earlier version was called MEGACO) and MGCP ([RFC 3435](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3435)) can carry SDP;
- the Session Announcement Protocol ([RFC 2974](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2974)) can carry SDP.

Which of those you will see in present-day network traffic is another matter.

As for the protocols on top of which those run, well, most of them run on top of TCP or possibly UDP, or on top of something that ultimately runs on top of TCP or possibly UDP, which means that they will then run on top of IPv4 or IPv6, which means that they will then run on top of any link layer that can transport IPv4 or IPv6, meaning Ethernet and 802.11 and PPP and....

However, ISUP, at least, can run on top of old-fashioned telephony networking stacks, such as the [Signaling System No. 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signalling_System_No._7) stack; whether it transports SDP when run on those stacks is another matter.

Comment: That is very good! One more question, are all these used to initiate RTP streams?

Comment: In theory, all of them could be used to initiate an RTP or other stream.  Whether any do in practice is another matter, but it's best to assume that any of them can be.